# Что за конструкция nodejs JavaScript js () =>

Tags: javascript, node.js

Что за конструкция JavaScript js () =>

Например () => resolve(collect)

или () => {...}

или (a,b) => {...}

Answer (score 4):

Это стрелочные функции.

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
```

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions