# Как правильно прочитать тело () => функции?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Встретил функцию в `react` коде:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.increment(), 1000/INTERVAL);
}
```

И вот этот участок не понятно как прочесть `() => this.increment(), 1000/INTERVAL`.

Он явно что-то возвращает так как данные сетятся, но что выполниться икак понимать эту запятую `this.increment()    ,    1000/INTERVAL`.

Объясните пожалуйста как это читать. Спасибо.

Comment: запятая в данном случае разделяет параметры передаваемые в функцию setInterval

Comment: @Grundy а () => тогда зачем?

Comment: это часть первого параметра [стрелочная функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706113/186999)

Comment: @Grundy а почему вы не отметили вопрос дубликатом? Стрелочные функции уже явно не один раз обсуждались.

Comment: @smellyshovel, я сначала не уверен был, что вопрос именно в стрелочных функциях, а не в значении запятой. А теперь смотрю какой больше ответ подойдет

Comment: @Grundy ну, судя по заголовку, вопрос явно не о запятой. На вашем месте я бы отметил дубликатом. Хотя вам видней, конечно.

Comment: Вопрос не в стрелочных функциях а в том что как такое может быть что-бы на вход функция принималась а не объект. С Java переезжаем.

Comment: @Pavel, _как такое может быть что-бы на вход функция принималась а не объект._ - прими это как данность :-D

Comment: @Pavel а, вот оно что. Тогда извиняюсь за наезд. Да, Grundy выше дело говорит XD

Comment: @smellyshovel все ок спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такая запись `() =>`    является синтаксисом стрелочной функции. Таким образом код можно переписать так:

```
componentDidMount() {
      let _this = this;
      this.timerID = setInterval(function() {_this.increment();}, 1000/INTERVAL);
    }
```

Пришлось присвоить ссылку на объект `this` временной переменной `_this`, из-за того, что функции в старом стиле заменяют его. Подробнее читайте в [статье про стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Запятая в данном случае является разделителем аргументов. Так `setInterval` у вас принимает на вход функцию и интервал времени в мс через который эта функция будет вызываться.

Comment: а почему так нельзя? `setInterval(this.increment(), 1000/INTERVAL)`

Comment: @Pavel, можно, просто результат будет неожиданным

Comment: @Grundy тоесть что значит неожиданным? Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @Pavel setInterval принимает первым аргументом функцию, а при **this.increment()** - это будет уже результат вызова increment()

Comment: @Pavel, я имею ввиду, что первый параметр в setInterval, Должна быть функция. А в твоем пример ты передаешь как первый параметр **результат вызова** `this.increment()` а не саму функцию `this.increment`, это означает, что данная функция вызовется один раз перед запуском интервала и все

Comment: @Grundy а! все я понял тебя спасибо.

Comment: `setInterval(function() {this.increment()` <- тут this будет уже другой. Так что так код переписывать нельзя. Работать не будет